# python pass list values to a functions as input

Tags: python, list, function

```
PersonList = [['Arajit', 'Das', '1976-2-16', '+918582531161', 25],
 ['Ranjan', 'Saha', '1987-6-24', '+919983687697', 25],
 ['Kishore', 'Kumar', '1998-11-23', '+918290368771', 23]]

def check(a, b, c, d, e):
    print(a, b, c, d, e)

for i in PersonList:
    print(i)
    check('Arajit', 'Das', '1976-2-16', '+918582531161', 25)
```

`want to pass a list values into function like in the above code`

**check('Arajit', 'Das', '1976-2-16', '+918582531161', 25) from i**

Comment: Use unpacking `check(*i)`.

Comment: or just pass a the list itself and not each element separately. this way you can just do `check(i)`